# How do I loop through an array in an external JS file using VueJS CDN?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have created a page which uses VueJs via the CDN and am trying to figure how to loop the data in an array from an external JS file. I have tried to import the data as below, but I get an undefined error in my console.

My loop in my index.html is as below;

```
        <ul>
            <li v-for="animal in animals">
              {{ animal.type }}
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Then the JS at the end of this index.html is as follows;

```
<script src="js/list.js"></script>
var app = new Vue({
    router: router,
    el: '#app',
    data() {
      return {
        animals: animals
      };
    }
});
```

Thne my external JS file containing the array is called list.js;

```
export animals [
    {
        type: 'Cat'
    },
    {
        Type: 'Dog'
    }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

This really doesn't have much to do with vue, but how you are trying to bring in the data.

If you are going to use the script tag, the export of animals won't work.

If this is just to get started, in list.js, you could just do

```
var animals = [ ... your data ];
```

Or if you want to use export....

change your export to

```
export const animals = [
    {
        type: 'Cat'
    },
    {
        Type: 'Dog'
    }
];
```

```html
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8" />  
      <div id="testapp"> 
          <ul>
                <li v-for="animal in animals">
                  {{ animal.type }}
                </li>
            </ul>
      </div>  
    </head>
    <body> 
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
      <script type="module">  
          import {animals} from "/scripts/list.js"
          var app = new Vue({    
          el: '#testapp',
          data() {
            return {
            animals: animals
          };      
        }
        });       
      </script>
      
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Both suggested answers result in two errors SyntaxError: export declarations may only appear at top level of a module & SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module

Comment: oh yes, I fixed your export  ```export animals [``` as well, updated my answer with the fixed version

Answer (score 0):

In your list.js file, you must export as const, like this.

```
export const animals = [
    {
        type: 'Cat'
    },
    {
        Type: 'Dog'
    }
]
```

And import it like this (inside your .js file):

```
import { animals } from 'js/list.js'

var app = new Vue({
    router: router,
    el: '#app',
    data() {
      return {
        animals: animals //you can use animal in data like this
      };
    }
});
```

After that you can loop as you like,...

Comment: It is important to mark the script tag containing the `import` with `type="module"` as well. Same goes for files/code containing `exports`.